Dealing with confidential modules in a Python code: are conditional imports possible?
Let say I have a Python code with a src source folder. Inside this folder is a subfolder confidential (typically a git submodule) that is confidential and only selected users of the code can access.
I am trying to find a robust way to deal with this confidential part of the code. I want to make sure all users can run the code, even if they don't have the confidential source files.
My main file would look like this :
try:
    from src.confidential.function import function
except ImportError:
    def function(*args):
    return 0, 0

# main code
user_can_access_confidential_code = False
a = 1
b = 2
if user_can_access_confidential_code:
    c, d = function(a, b)

I am not very satisfied with this way of working as it implies a potentially large try/except section should there be many confidential functions to import conditionally. In addition, I could not find a way to simplify the return part of the function.
Is there an efficient way to deal with such conditional import ? I would like to add that, though it does not appear in the mwe, the code is running with Numba.

Why do you need the def at all if it won't be called?

@wim with Numba, if I don't define a function, the pre-compilation will crash.

I think I would create a default implementation of the API that had sane return values that could be overridden by the premium version.
